# Use sql variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql

I currently have a site set up where the user has three interdependent dropdown boxes that allow the user to select an individual name from a group of teams. I am able to get the selected value from the boxes and pass them on to the javascript, reloading the page with the select variables using GET method.

HOWEVER, what I need to do is find a way to pass on the primary key of the individual name they have selected. I have the primary key in the SQL statement, but am not clearly thinking of a way that I can bring it in to the javascript so that I can pass it on to the next page for post processing.

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: embed the values in the page when the server builds it. `<option value="$primary_key_here">$name</option>`. Or pass the data around as ajax requests. You have lots of choices. JS itself won't care where the data came from. you could have an army of trained monkeys banging on keyboards randomly for all JS cares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the primary key in the value attribute of the option tag, and the display name of the team in the html attribute.

```
<select>
    <option value='id' >Team 1</option>
</select>
```

Then just pass around the id, and look up the name before you send it back to the html.

Comment: Yes, I think I jumped the gun posting the question. Thought of this right after I submitted, but this is definitely the way to go. Thanks a lot.